# Find out when a new domain appears in search results

Tags: seo, google, domains, search-results

Does anyone know a way to perform the following:

I want to know whenever a new domain starts appearing in the google search results for a particular query.

For a given google search query, I'd like to receive an alert whenever a new domain pops up and starts appearing in the search results for that query.

Alternatively, it would be great if you could just sort google search results by the age of the domain, making it easy to find new sites.

As far as I can tell you can only sort by when the page was "last updated".

Is something like this possible?

EDIT: Following John's suggestion of Google Alerts. The problem with Google Alerts is that it sends you any new PAGES appearing in the search results, not just new DOMAINS.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) can do this. Your search query might look like `site:yoursite.com search terms`

Comment: Thanks John! yeah I played with google alerts but it sends you new PAGES that appear in the search results which results in a lot of noise and makes it very difficult to spot just the new DOMAINS.

Comment: Google doesn't rank or index domains. They only do pages. And if one page is found than the domain is indexed. If you want to know when pages from a new domain appear, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything can be done, but what you are looking for can not be done with an alert properly and there are not any tools thinking in this way.

I do believe this can be done, however you have to pre-define the exact details and how deep to crawl google. Then you need to use API tools to collect that data and then collect domain age, etc. You may find older sites appearing for the parameters you are looking for as it may be an older domain sold on Auction and re-themed for a market you are looking for.

Now are you getting into a combo of scraping and API usage. So you have to think how far you are willing to go and can you find someone who knows how to do this!